# IBM Worklight Server repository

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

I have been following this step from IBM :

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc%2Fadmin%2Fc_installation.html

For installing IBM Worklight Server. But I can't find any repository or direct link to download IBM Worklight Server. Or does it come together with IBM Developer Studio or it really a package to install. I confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Worklight studio comes with an embedded Worklight server. The instructions you linked to above are for installing a standalone Worklight server. You will need such a server for production.
The Worklight studio is for free. Worklight studio requires a purchased license from IBM. Once you have that license, you can download the Worklight server from "IBM Passport Advantage" website in http://www-01.ibm.com/software/passportadvantage/pao_customer.html